# Power BI reports in Delphi

Tags: delphi, powerbi

I am new to Power BI and would like to be able to display pre-created Power BI reports in Delphi. I searched on the internet using Google but found little information for Delphi developers, just general information on Power BI. I am using Delphi 10.2.3.

Comment: But what is your question exactly?

Comment: Is my question not clear enough? Would I use a browser component in Delphi to display a Power BI report, or are there Power BI components available for Delphi.

Comment: No, there are no components for Delphi. The reports must be shown in web browser.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Actually based on the information on their site tehre is Power BI API available to desktop enviroments using various Technologies like .NET, Power BI REST API, JavaScript API etc. https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/developers/ So it might not be necessary for Power BI reports to be shown in web browser. But I gues noone had made pascal binding for Power BI API so far

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes, I mean the reports must be shown in web browser component in his Delphi app (e.g. TWebBrowser).

Answer (score 2):

To embed a report, you must authenticate yourself and acquire an access token. It will be used in further calls to Power BI REST API.

Normally, this access token is acquired using [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries), but I have doubts you will find one for Delphi. You may take a look at this question to see how you can do this using raw web requests in Delphi: [How to connect a Delphi desktop app to a third-party Dynamics 365 app using OAuth 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310503/how-to-connect-a-delphi-desktop-app-to-a-third-party-dynamics-365-app-using-oaut)

When you acquired an access token, get the report's embedUrl using [Get Report In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportingroup) API.

Embedding of Power BI reports is basically loading them in a  in a web page. [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/01/27/integrate-power-bi-dashboards-reports-and-tiles-into-a-wpf-application/) demo shows you how to embed the report in a WPF application. You can do the same in Delphi. Basically you need to copy `powerbi.js`, `ReportLoader.js` and `ReportLoader.html` files from the demo to your project. The first file is the Power BI client. The second is JavaScript code, which you need to run to load the report in the third one. From your code you need to navigate to `ReportLoader.html` file and run `LoadEmbeddedObject` JavaScript function from `ReportLoader.js`, passing to it the embedUrl of your report, your access token and the Id of the report to be embedded. I can't tell you how to call this function in Delphi, but the WPF demo code may give you some ideas.

Good luck!