# connect to Power Bi with delphi xe10.4.2

Tags: delphi, powerbi-desktop, delphi-xe, delphi-10.4.2

I want to write a program with Delphi that uses pbi reports
Is there a solution?
I saw similar work with other platforms but I need it done in Delphi

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should explain in more detail what you need. This explanation is too generic. You can use TWebBrowser (Delphi component) to open your PBIReports inside your app.

Comment: From what I can find on internet there are SDK's only for .NET, NodeJS, Angular and JavaScript. [Microsoft Power BI API - SDKs](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/microsoft-power-bi/sdks). Also there are REST API's for power BI [Using the Power BI REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/). So no there doesn't seem to be out of box solution for Delphi at this time

Comment: Thankful
I wrote a program that I want to develop its various reporting module using powerBI
This means that the user who is using this Delphi program can see the report by selecting an option; Without entering powerbi.
It is not a problem to see in which component of the report, but I do not know how I should connect to the pbi report at all or what component I should use and how to tell pbi how to display the report.
Thank you for giving me a simple program

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738739/how-to-integrate-power-bi-in-a-delphi-desktop-application/56750348#56750348 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702569/power-bi-reports-in-delphi/53702858#53702858